# Hide/show DIVs one at a time, despite having the same class

Tags: jquery

How could I hide/show DIVs that have the same class one at a time?

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hkP7N/1/

When clicking "Hide content 1" or "Hide content 2", the content in both DIVs disappears. I'd need only the appropriate content to be affected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.hide-button').click( function() {
    $('.content').toggle();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/hkP7N/2/

Using `next` you can target the next element

Or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hkP7N/3/

You can use `slideToggle` as well, gives a nice effect: http://jsfiddle.net/hkP7N/8/

Comment: Hmm, Xander beat me to my second solution

Comment: Yep, works great. What if the toggle was replaced by a css event though? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nYAD3/

Comment: Not sure what you mean? How would that be triggered? And where from? It's all about locating the element to want to toggle in the DOM

Comment: What I mean is that everything would be exactly the same as in your jsfiddle, except that instead of the content being hidden or sliding, it would be faded out and then back in again. How would one go about achieving that?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.hide-button').click( function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.content').toggle();
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/5LZeC/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.hide-button').click( function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.content').toggle();
});
```

[Here it is working with your example.](http://jsfiddle.net/hkP7N/6/)